# pg_dump suddenly not dumping all tables

Tags: postgresql

For years now we have used this command to dump data from our database calle "apflora":

```
pg_dump --file=/shared/$FILENAME -Fc -Z9 -o apflora
```

And it has always worked.
We do this on the ubuntu server. The script then sends the data to a dropbox account (it is part of a bash script that sets $FILENAME).

Since a few days (I need to pinpoint that more precisely) suddenly only 35 of 40 tables are included in the backups.

When restoring a database the log contains many messages like this:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "ap" does not exist
```

This also happens when I backup the same database using pgAdminIII LTS by BigSQL

I checked the logs at

```
/var/log/postgresql
```

but could not find anything logged when the backups run.

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

We use

- PostgreSQL 9.6
- Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: what is the line just before the `pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "ap" does not exist`?..

Comment: Does the dump complete normally or is the dump file truncated?

Comment: Vao Tsung: You were on the right track: At the start of several hundred lines pgcrypto was mentioned (see answer). Thanks both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer rather surprised me.

Actually, the backups created on ubuntu were completely o.k.

The problem occurred when restoring from a backup. The reason was that 5 of the tables use a UUID. For which the extension "pgcrypto" is needed. And pgcrypto could not be installed, because there seems to be an error in BigSQL's macOs build of postgresql (https://www.bigsql.org/postgresql/installers.jsp). And this resulted in these tables not being restored.

Well, that seems easy to solve, right? I uninstalled this version of PostgreSQL and installed EnterpriseDB's version (https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads#macosx). Only problem here: pgAdmin4 is (at the time of writing in v1.2) extremely buggy. I could try as much as I wanted, it would not restore a backup without creating errors :-(

(I know of several other bugs too, so please don't use v1.2 yet)

In the end my solution was to install only the pgAdminIII LTS from BigSQL (https://www.bigsql.org/pgadmin3/index.jsp) using their package manager (https://www.bigsql.org/package-manager.jsp). And keeping the PostgreSQL from EnterpriseDB.

Now I can finally install pgcrypto AND restore backups :-)

Hope this helps others with macOs.

Thanks Vao Tsung and Curt Evans for pitching in!

Comment: I don't understand what pgAdmin has to do with restoring backups? Backups (or actually: dumps) are restores using `pg_restore`

Comment: Even though I do use pg_dump on servers I like to use a graphical interface on my PC and Mac. pgAdmin has a menu to backup and restore that of course uses pg_dump and pg_restore in the background

Comment: Of course pgAdmin was not the reason why the tables were not restored, rather an error in BigSQL's pgcrypto extension